# How to valiadate a xml document with Multiple xml-schemas

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, validation

xmlns:m="http://www.MangoDSP.com/mav/wsdl" as localfile:"ma.wsdl"
xmlns:m0="http://www.MangoDSP.com/schema"  as localfile:"MaTypes.xsd"

how can i validate it.

Comment: How would you validate an XML document with a single XML Schema?

Comment: Did you want to post the XML? Post it, then select the XML and press Control-K (the button with 1001010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done this in a while (years, really) and once again I'm posting from my Linux laptop, so please forgive the fuzziness.

```
private bool isValid;
private ArrayList exceptionList;

public bool Validate()
{
    isValid = true;
    exceptionList = new ArrayList();

    XmlTextReader reader;
    XmlSchema schema;
    XmlSchemaCollection schemas = new XmlSchemaCollection();

    reader = new XmlTextReader( "schema file 1" );
    schema = XmlSchema.Read( reader, new ValidationEventHandler( ValidationError ) );
    schemas.Add( schema );

    reader = new XmlTextReader( "schema file 2" );
    schema = XmlSchema.Read( reader, new ValidationEventHandler( ValidationError ) );
    schemas.Add( schema );

    reader = new XmlTextReader( "validate this file" );

    XmlValidatingReader validatingReader;

    validatingReader = new XmlValidatingReader( reader );
    validatingReader.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler( ValidationError );
    validatingReader.Schemas.Add( schemas );

    isValid = true;
    exceptionList = new ArrayList();

    while ( validatingReader.Read() );

    return isValid;
}

private void ValidationError( object sender, ValidationEventArgs e )
{
    isValid = false;
    exceptionList.Add( e.Exception );
}
```

You'll also want to do some error handling and resource cleanup.